# 4D np.array multiplied by a 2D np.array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, 4d

I have two numpy arrays :

- M of shape (n_nodes, n_nodes, n_clusters, n_clusters)
- tau of shape (n_nodes, n_clusters)
  I want to get the matrix K such that
  `K[i,j,k,l] = M[i,j]**tau[j,l]`
  I want to do it without any for loop.
  I tried `K = M ** tau[:, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]`
  but it doesn't work
  Anyone has an answer please ?

`K = M ** tau[:, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]`

Comment: Judging from `K[i,j,k,l] = M[i,j]**tau[j,l]`, I think you might need `K = M ** tau[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, :]` instead. Note how the axes align differently! Is that something you tried?

Comment: Yes I already tried and it doesn't work either
It turns out the calculus :
K = M ** tau[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis, :]
works
Not sure to understand why, but happy to have what I need !

Comment: Um, isn't that exactly what Chrysophylaxs suggested?

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake sorry :)